# Polymorphic model only working on one model

Tags: laravel

I currently have a polymorphic relationship using a model like so:

The model is called `Productable`
In the model I have:

```
public function productable()
{
  return $this->morphTo();
}
```

I have another model called `Product` that has access to the Productable model like so:

```
public function productDetails()
{
  return $this->morphMany(Productable::class, 'productable');
}
```

This works as expected and I can create a record in the Productable table like so:

```
  $p = new Product;
  $p->product_name = $request->product_name;
  $p->product_type = $request->product_type;
  $p->category_id = $request->product_category;
  $p->description = $request->product_description;

  $p->save();

  $p->productDetails()->create([
    'product_id' => $p->id,
  ]);
```

However the issue is I have another model called `Media`
which also has:

public function productDetails()
{
return $this->morphMany(Productable::class, 'productable');
}

On that model I attempt to write a record like so:

```
              $pMedia = new Media;
              $pMedia->productDetails()->create([
                'product_id' => $p->id,
                'productable_id' => $value,
              ]);
```

The error I get is:

```
Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'productable_id' cannot be null (SQL: insert into `productables` (`product_id`, `productable_id`, `productable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (38, ?, App\Models\Media, 2021-03-04 18:46:51, 2021-03-04 18:46:51))
```

What am I doing wrong here? Shouldn't I be to write to Media in the same way?  I'm wondering what I'm missing.

Comment: What does `dd/var_dump($value)` shows? are you sure $value isn't null?

Comment: string(1) "1" @SanderVisser

Comment: At least i'm sure you have to set 2 fields `productable_type` and `productable_id` this is needed to know the correct model where it relates to.

Comment: But doesn't productable_type automatically set?  @SanderVisser on the Product one it automatically sets.

Comment: $pMedia = new Media;
                      $pMedia->productDetails()->create([
                        'product_id' => 12,
                        'productable_id' => 32,
                      ]); @SanderVisser setting it statically like this gives the same error

Comment: Sorry yes you are right, i'm not sure why `productable_id` is `null` in this case.

Comment: THANK YOU FOR TRYING TO HELP! @SanderVisser

Comment: What you could try is ` $pMedia->save();` after creating

Comment: The challenge with that is that I need to save a new Media record then which I'm not trying to do.  I just want to save to the Productables.  @SanderVisser

Comment: You need to save the Media record otherwise it doesn't have an id to set, you can make the `productable` relation nullable in your table creation in your migration/database

Comment: Ok so that was it.  The issue was that since I wasn't getting the Media record the id wasn't being identified.  It wouldn't allow me to statically set the 'productable_id'.  @SanderVisser want to put it as an answer so I can give you credit?